# Is it possible to update an XML using XSLT for an array of values?

Tags: xml, xslt

Consider I have an xml like

```
<reasonConfig>
    <reasons/>
</reasonConfig>
```

I can have an array of string as input and wanted to update  node with these values. The required output will be like

```
<reasonConfig>
    <reasons>
        <reason value="First Form"/>
        <reason value="Second Form"/>
        <reason value="Third Form"/>
    </reasons>
</reasonConfig>
```

The array of String have values like {"First Form", "Second Form", "Third Form"}

Presently I will make a copy of particular node and update the "value" String with below xsl code for n times.

```
<xsl:param name="value" />
<xsl:template match="reason">
<reason value="{$value}"></reason >
</xsl:template>
```

Is there any way to do the complete transformation in a step? like receiving an array of input values and add new rows corresponding to that in xml?

Comment: Which XSLT processor will you be using for this?

Comment: Which other programming language or framework are you using where you have that array of strings that you want to pass to XSLT? How do you currently run the XSLT?

Comment: I use Java and TransformerFactory for this.

Comment: Interchanging data like an "array of strings" with an XSLT processor depends on the XSLT version (only XSLT 3 with XPath 3.1 has a data type `array(xs:string)` that maps directly to an "array of strings") and even then of course it depends on how you run the XSLT, which programming language you have with that array of strings, how it interfaces with the XSLT processor. For Saxon 9.8 and XSLT 3 see an XSLT example at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTAf, whether that helps for your particular problem depends on whether you use Saxon and can use its API to pass in such an array.

Comment: Assuming that means you're using Xalan, you could pass the "array of strings" as a delimited string instead. Then use the EXSLT  `str:tokenize()` extension function to parse the string, and create a node for each token.

Answer (score 1):

A variant of [michael-hor257k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016153/michael-hor257k)'s suggestion is using a simple XSLT-1.0 processor like `xsltproc` (or any other XSLT-1.0 one) and pass the strings as a global parameter to the stylesheet.

Here, the parameter is called `strings` and the different values are delimited by commas. This stylesheet uses a recursive template to add the `<reason...>` elements with the corresponding `value` atributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="strings" />

  <xsl:template match="/reasonConfig">
    <xsl:copy>
        <reasons>
            <xsl:call-template name="rs">
                <xsl:with-param name="strs" select="concat($strings,',')" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </reasons>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="rs">
    <xsl:param name="strs" />
    <xsl:if test="$strs != ''">
        <reason>
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($strs,','))" />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </reason>
        <xsl:call-template name="rs">
            <xsl:with-param name="strs" select="substring-after($strs,',')" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, for example, if you pass values with a parameter to the XSLT stylesheet, you can do it with the linux program `xsltproc` like this:

```
xsltproc --stringparam strings "ab,cd,ef" test.xslt test.xml
```

and the output will be

```
<reasonConfig>
  <reasons>
    <reason value="ab"/>
    <reason value="cd"/>
    <reason value="ef"/>
  </reasons>
</reasonConfig>
```

---

Using Java, the approach is quite similar:
One possibility would be using the [`StringJoiner` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) to generate the comma-separated string. Then pass this string to the XSLT processor.

For `javax.xml.transform.Transformer` you can do this with the [`setParameter` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#setParameter(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) like this (adjust `arrayStringWithValues`):

```
// Create and configure XSLT Transformer 
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslt));
transformer.setParameter("strings", arrayStringWithValues);
```